# submit form2 without submitting form1 in jsp having 2 forms

Tags: java, jsp, struts

i am using two forms in a jsp page.i want to submit form2 but it needs first form1 to be submitted then second form will be submitted.please help me how to only submit form2 without submitting form1 ..thankyou :)

```
        <html:form action="action1">
<html:submit property=method><bean:message key="userform.login"/></html:submit>
        </html:form>

        <html:form action="action2">
<html:submit property=method><bean:message key="userform.contactus"/></html:submit></html:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going to be able to submit a form without leaving the page unless you use :

Ajax ( as suggested ) - and on the 'success' return post form 2

or an Iframe

Iframe - post into an iframe on the page, the iframe page can trigger the posting of form2 (if form1 post is successful) by using javascript 'parent.form2.submit()'

Answer (score 2):

You would need to submit one form via Ajax, and in the callback, do whatever you need to with the results of submitting the first form. Then the second form can be submitted normally.

IMO your usecase seems a little twisted: you shouldn't need to be logged in to "contact us" first of all. If the goal is to include user info in the "contact us" form, then (a) why show a "contact us" link before you can use it, and/or (b) just do normal "you must be logged in" processing and don't worry about the convolutions of doing what you're doing.

Alternatively, have an additional login form on the "contact us" page and require it as part of the form validation, and skip all of these issues, create a smoother user experience, and make your development that much easier.

Comment: but i dont want to use ajax.and when i click on submit of form2 it goes to form 1 and form2 doesnt gets submitted ..what should i do in this case.form2 gets submitted only when form 1 is submitted ..please help

Comment: @vishu10061990 I don't understand what you're saying; if you're clicking on form 2's submit and form 1 is being submitted then either your Struts configuration is wrong, or your JSP/HTML is wrong. You can only submit one form at a time--that's just the way it is.

Comment: form 1 is not being submitted .. when i click on form2 submit button ..nothing happens page srolls to form1 only ..

Comment: @vishu10061990 Then either your HTML isn't rendering what you think it is, or it's not submitting what you think it is, or the action you're submitting to isn't doing what you think it is.